# iCloud Documents & Data App Icon Unknown

Tags: iphone, icloud

I'm noticing that my game's app icon and name are listed as "Unknown" in the device's settings for Documents and Data.  Is it safe to assume this is because the game is not yet released on the App Store?  I know Game Center users a sandbox server for storing data when an app isn't yet released... it looks like iCloud uses live servers?

Or am I setting something up wrong?  Can anyone confirm one way or another?[image: Missing App Icon and Name in Documents and Data for iCloud]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do believe this was the case - the live app store did not yet know the app, so it showed a blank icon and unknown.