# Specifying app name for iCloud "Manage Storage" list

Tags: ios, synchronization, icloud, info.plist, uti

Where does iCloud source the app name that it displays in the iCloud preferences?

- iOS: `Settings.app > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Store > Documents & Data`
- OSX: `System Preferences > iCloud > Manage ...`

I know that [iCloud will list an app as "Unknown" with a blank icon initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896657/icloud-documents-data-app-icon-unknown) (and that did happen in my case), however my app is now appearing in this list by its 'internal' name rather than its 'pretty' name (the app update containing iCloud is not yet submitted so this is doubly strange).

My gut says that the name would be defined as part of the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` or `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` sections in my app's `info.plist` but the name iCloud's using only appears in the UTI values there. Nor does the iCloud value match the app's `CFBundleDisplayName` or the description attached to the App ID in the provisioning portal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue seems to only have been present during development. Once the update (containing iCloud functionality) was released my app began to show up in the iCloud preferences under its  `CFBundleDisplayName`

Comment: Do you know what happens if the same iCloud data is used by multiple apps with different names?

Comment: I have this happening in a live app. Both the wrong name (not the defined bundle name) is being used in `Settings > iCloud > Manage Storage`, and the white icon is displayed (the one with the 'construction lines'). I've seen users submit screenshots with the same issue so I know it's not just me. Also, on my devices it seems to affect **Pixelmator** as well - it has the white icon, and it's not the bundle name being used (capitalisation wrong). It's not a missing icon, as if you go to the root screen in Settings down where the apps are, the icons are all there.

Comment: @murat did you get an answer to this? I have the same issue with a store that's used with multiple apps.

Comment: @ngb sorry, I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone using Core Data and syncing via iCloud:
You will need to give your model file, i.e. the .xcdatamodeld file, the same name as your app. That is inherited by the corresponding .momd file which you then need to use in your URL definition for the iCloud.
This filename is what the iCloud "Manage Storage" search picks up, not the app name.